# Impact on system's performance due to other users logging in

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

If some user just logs into a server and uses it for accessing another server using ssh. Does this behaviour impact the routing server in any way: How does it affect the RAM, cache's, CPU performance etc.

For example if I first log into one server using: ssh userName@server1.com
And from server1.com I ssh into another server using: ssh userName@server2.com

So, how does this affect the RAM, cache, CPU, and other performance parameters of server1.

Actually I need a theoretical proof as to why server1's RAM,cache, CPU etc will get affected by just using it to route to server2. E.g. one of the theoretical reasons is when data is scp though server1, then server1's CPU, cache and RAM usage will increase. Is there some other reason?

Comment: What “system cache” do you mean?

Comment: @lxg I mean the system cache's as explained in http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-clear-cached-memory-on-ubuntu.html

Comment: Then you should explicitely mention that you're refering to cached memory. By the way, I'm afraid your question is too broad and quite unclear. You may need to explain more specifically what the problem is and what you've done to solve it.

Comment: @lxg My question is if some user just logs into a server and uses it for accessing another server using ssh. Does this behaviour impact the routing server in any way: How does it affect the RAM, cache's, CPU performance etc

Comment: This is a fair question, but from what you've wrote above, I would never have guessed that this is the essence of your pondering. Maybe you should rephrase the entire question. (The parts about your database, the administrator, and the “theoretical proofs” are irrelevant IMHO.)